# Display MenuItems in multiple columns in JFace/swt

Tags: swt, jface

I have a long list of MenuItems (> 100) for a popup menu and wanted to put them into several columns instead of default 1 column.
Tried with the below code but not successful:

```java
    public class CodeSnippet {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
         final Composite c2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
         c2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
         Menu menu = new Menu(c2);
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.RADIO);
            item.setText ("Item " + i);
        }

        shell.setMenu (menu);
        shell.setSize (300, 300);
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }

}
```

Despite of providing gridlayout for the Control used for Menu don't know why it displays in a Single column only.

Any clue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the layout of items in a Menu, the layout is determined by the native code on your platform.

Comment: Greg-449 ,many thanks for the needful info. But than somehow I have to accommodate a long list of Menu items for a pop menu. Is it possible to add a table to the pop-up Menu? idea is, create buttons instead of menu items and put them into a table and show the table when user hovers on the menu.

Comment: I think the last reply was kinda  dumbo from my end. sorry. I have to just add a mouse listener and show the the table filled with buttons when user hovers the same menu. Any way thanks.